# How to set the cookie expiration time to 30 minutes when using aws-amplify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

The following code is the manual configuration for the amplify auth and I just want to set `expires` under `cookieStorage` to 30 minutes instead of 365 days.

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

    Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {

            // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
            identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',

            // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
            region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

            // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region 
            // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
            identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',

            // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
            userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

            // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
            userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',

            // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
            mandatorySignIn: false,

            // OPTIONAL - Configuration for cookie storage
            cookieStorage: {
            // REQUIRED - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
                domain: '.yourdomain.com',
            // OPTIONAL - Cookie path
                path: '/',
            // OPTIONAL - Cookie expiration in days
                expires: 365,
            // OPTIONAL - Cookie secure flag
                secure: true
            },

            // OPTIONAL - customized storage object
            storage: new MyStorage(),

            // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
            authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fraction of a day. 0.5 would be 12hours. 30 Minutes would be ~0.02.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question!

I think you can set only day as unit and nothing else.

From documentation:

```
The CookieStorage object receives a map (data) in its constructor that
may have these values:

data.domain Cookies domain (mandatory)
data.path Cookies path (default: '/') 
data.expires Cookie expiration (in days, default: 365)
data.secure Cookie secure flag (default: true)
```

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js